# Does PostgreSQL store a database per file, similarly to SQLite?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

If I am correct, SQLite stores a database per file, and a file can't store more than one databases.

How does PostgreSQL store a database in terms of file(s)? Does it also store a database per file, and a file can't store more than one databases?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage.html

Answer (score 4):

(SQLite uses more than one file for the [rollback journal](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) or when in [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).)

The PostgreSQL database file layout is documented in its [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html):

> Each table and index is stored in a separate file. For ordinary relations, these files are named after the table or index's filenode number, which can be found in `pg_class.relfilenode`. […] in addition to the main file (a/k/a main fork), each table and index has a *free space map* …, which stores information about free space available in the relation. The free space map is stored in a file named with the filenode number plus the suffix `_fsm`. Tables also have a *visibility map*, stored in a fork with the suffix `_vm`, to track which pages are known to have no dead tuples. […]